# Blynk protocols That used for Arduino

Tags: arduino, mqtt, protocols, communication, blynk

Is the blynk platform takes the MQTT protocol ?
for communication from the Arduino what is the protocols it used for blynk platform ?

Answer (score 1):

Blynk uses its own proprietary binary protocol to communicate from Blynk library on the IoT device to Blynk cloud servers. This allows to use Blynk on microcontrollers with limited memory space.

To use Blynk Cloud and Blynk App you have to use the Blynk library on the IoT device.

*I am not affiliated with Blynk.*